# Reuse code for fading an element/in and out, so that I don't have to repeat my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a div with a link and on click should open a jQuery dialog above/within the div itself with fadein and out.

I've tried to examplify it with this image: http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/9852/exampled.jpg

**HTML**

```html
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none">Add to cart</div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
$('.div').click(function(){
   $('#dialog').fadeToggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.div{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #FFECA2;
    width: 123px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 9px;
    position:relative;
}

#dialog {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:0; top:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background-color: #FFFEDF;
    border: 1px solid #FFECA2;
    width: 123px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 9px;
}​
```

I have put together a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/725Me/

Now, the problem is: if i have **a lot of div elements**, do I have to define

`<div id="dialog"> Add to cart </div>` for each div? Would it be possible to define it only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

If you don't want to define the `<div class="dialog">Add to cart</div>` markup for every div, you can use jQuery to apply it the first time each div is clicked. (Notice that I changed the ID `dialog` to a class `dialog` instead. An ID have to be unique for each element, which is not going to work if we are going to reuse this code for each div).

When a div is clicked, we check if the `dialog` class has been added already, otherwise we append it. Then we `fadeToggle()` as usual.

Something like this:

```
$('.div').click(function() {
    if ($(".dialog", this).length === 0) {
        $("<div class=\"dialog\">Add to cart</div>").appendTo(this);
    }
    $(".dialog", this).fadeToggle();
})​;
```

Your markup would then be a bit simpler:

```
<div class="div">
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amete
</div>
<div class="div">
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amete
</div>
<div class="div">
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amete
</div>​
```

**A working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/725Me/4/

Answer (score 2):

IDs must be *unique*, You can use classes instead and try the following:

```
$('.div').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.dialog').fadeToggle();
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/725Me/2/)